# Android Studio 2.0 - Error:Execution failed for task app:compileDebugAidl

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-2.0

after upgrading my Android Studio 1.5 to 2.0 and my Android SDK Tools to 25.1.1 and Android SDK Build-tools 23.0.3 and gradle plugin to version 2.0.0 i get this error :

```
 Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'.
 > java.lang.RuntimeException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: A problem occurred starting process 'command '/home/rasool/android/adt.../sdk/build-tools/23.0.3/aidl''
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Call me crazy but i spent an entire day on my mac with  3.1 AS and i was not  able to get it working. tried different build tools, different AS versions, different branches which were working before, clean build, remove cache, invalidate cache.. nothing worked.

Then i restarted my mac and it started working magically ! So if any mac user is facing this, try to restart your mac before you attempt to fix it. !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the problem was that iam running a 64-bit version of linux and changed my OS recently and i forgot to install necessary 32-bit libraries.

in Ubuntu :

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32bz2-1.0 lib32stdc++6
```

in Fedora :

```
sudo yum install zlib.i686 ncurses-libs.i686 bzip2-libs.i686
```

if you get this error in Ubuntu :

```
E: Unable to locate package lib32bz2-1.0
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'lib32bz2-1.0'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'lib32bz2-1.0'
```

you can skip this library and use this command :

```
sudo apt-get install lib32z1 lib32ncurses5 lib32stdc++6
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `Build -> Clean Project`

Sometimes Gradle builds will fail due to duplicate build files in the project.